# Batch file to create .txt files with specific names: String001.txt, String002.txt, etc

Tags: batch-file, text-files, createfile, batching

Ive used the for loop below, but can only get it to ouput an incrementing number as the name. It ignores the string. (1.txt, 2.txt, etc.).

```
For /l %%x (1, 1, 9) do (echo string%%x > %%x.txt)
```

How do I add the static string in front of each incrementing number in the .txt file name?

I think it may need another variable to store the whole string and number together, then redirect that to filenames. But Im stumped...

Thanks for help.

Comment: Um... `echo string%%x > String%%x.txt`?

Comment: @Ken White: I guess didnt even need anything between "echo" and ">" but adding my string to the output name did the trick! Thanks! Im terrible at programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have leading zeroes you need a different approach:

```
@Echo off
for /l %%n in (1001,1,1009) do set n=%%n&call Echo string%%n:~-3%% >string%%n:~-3%%.txt
```

Comment: Nice! THATS exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no effort to write anything but the number followed by the .txt extension.

Try this instead:

```
for /l %%x (1, 1, 9) do (echo string%%x > String%%x.txt)
```